# Array prints out empty after appending data from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query the most popular hashtags in my database. The most popular hashtag has the most posts. First, this is how my Hashtags database looks like

```
Hashtags
    L firstHashtag
        L post1: true
        L post2: true
        L post3: true
        L post_count: 3
    L secondHashtag
        L post4: true
        L post5: true
        L post6: true
        L post7: true
        L post8: true
        L post_count: 5
    L thirdHashtag
        L post9: true
        L post_count: 1
```

I query their order based on their post count and fetch the 8 most popular hashtags like this:

```
func observePopularTags(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    REF_HASHTAG.queryOrdered(byChild: "post_count").queryLimited(toLast: 8).observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in
        completion(snapshot.key)
    })
}
```

Then I add them to an empty array

```
var hashtags: [String] = []
```

After that I call a function to observe & insert the popular hashtags in the array

```
func getHashtags() {
    Api.HashTag.observePopularTags { (name) in
        let hashtag = "#" + name
        // This works, it prints out each popular hashtag
        print(hashtag)
        self.hashtags.append(hashtag)
    }
    // When I print out the whole array, it prints an empty array.
    print("Hashtags: ", hashtags)
}
```

I call this function in the viewDidLoad method. However, when I print the array, it prints it out as an empty array. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. When you print `hashtags` it hasn't completed loading yet. Any code that requires access to the data from Firebase must be *inside* the completion handler. So:

```
func getHashtags() {
    Api.HashTag.observePopularTags { (name) in
        let hashtag = "#" + name
        // This works, it prints out each popular hashtag
        print(hashtag)
        self.hashtags.append(hashtag)
        print("Hashtags: ", hashtags)
    }
}
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419137/firebase-observe-called-after-following-command/47419386#47419386) I gave earlier today.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am trying to put the value in that array into a table view cell.The problem is that the table view runs before the data is loaded into the array. So what should I do in this case?